# CSS selectors for excluding by attribute presence

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, nokogiri

The document I am parsing has the following two styles of `td` tags (among other instances of `td` tags):

```
<td align="right" nowrap bgcolor="#A1C87A">...</td>

<td align="right" nowrap>...</td>
```

How do I write a selector which only selects the second type, and exclude all the other `td` tags?

```
document.css('td:not([bgcolor="#A1C87A"])')
```

excludes the first type, includes the second type plus all other `td` tags as well.

```
document.css('td[align="right"][nowrap]')
```

excludes all other `td` tags, but includes both types above.

Comment: Step 1 would be to write current HTML that doesn't include the align and bgcolor attributes. Try CSS instead.

Comment: The OP probably has no control over the HTML. What would be the point of parsing HTML you control?

Comment: @the Tin Man: So people can wiggle their finger at you and tell you what you should be doing instead, of course.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can simply combine the `:not` selector with the other attribute selectors:

```
document.css('td:not([bgcolor="#A1C87A"])[align="right"][nowrap]')
```

You could even put the `:not` after the others (it doesn’t need to be right next to the element name):

```
document.css('td[align="right"][nowrap]:not([bgcolor="#A1C87A"])')
```

These will both select all `td` elements that have `bgcolor="#A1C87A"` and `nowrap` but don’t have `align="right"`, which is what you’re after.

Comment: Thanks! Went with `td[align="right"][nowrap]:not([bgcolor])` after finding another instance of `bgcolor="white"` that I had to exclude.

Comment: what do I do if I have background : blue in my css and not bgcolor

Answer (score 0):

`td:not([align="right"][nowrap][bgcolor])` should be enough for what you want

Comment: Thanks. This seems to not exclude all other td tags.

Answer (score 0):

```
td[nowrap][bgcolor] ~ td[nowrap] { code };
```

Comment: Thanks. Looks like this is including all `td` tags with `align`, `bicolor` and `nowrap` attributes.